# Show app update message to android users when they opened the app

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way that I can indicate my android app users to update their app in PlayStore. **I haven't written any code to "check version number and show an app update message", in my previous app.** What I have known so far that in this situation some solutions could be, like:

1. Play store will fix this issue(by sending push notification) after a new version is updated.
2. I can send push notifications to the app users to inform them to update their apps.

**I am new to android app development. I know that this question is not making any sense because the codes are already compiled and I am not be able to do any edit to that code. The app communicate with the server in Json data format. But I am not able to send that "app update" message to the app by using one of the array keys, from server side. If I do, the app gets crash.**

**So, I am guessing if there any way that I can inform to those app users to update the app (may be via playstore), when they opened that app, in a dialogue box/something, with my custom message and it is not via the push notification message.**

Please suggest me the solutions other than those I have mentioned above. If it is impossible, then comment it also. I need to confirm it that what I have known so far is correct.

Comment: u have to add code and upload new apk to play store. after that you can give update message

Comment: If your users login with an email address, you could simply inform them by mail. Otherwise there is no option if you have not built in one. At least as far as I know.

Comment: Well it is quite simple to implement a feature like this, what you can do is create a php or node js app. Your app will communicate with the server,sending your server an app version and then in the server. If the server return that a new update is available prompt the user to update the app.
The simplest approach will be to create a json file and host it somewhere(pastebin). Make a get request to the json file parse the data and if the update is available do as required.

Comment: @SukritKumar : Well, how can it be helpful to inform those old versioned app users (who has currently installed that old versioned app) to update their app? Glad if you please give the solution in a step by step format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that play store will not show any notification to the user when new version of your apk is available.

Also you have to upload a new apk with code for checking update in your app and then only it will work.

For showing update dialog you can use the following library

[Version Checker Library](https://github.com/robohorse/gpversionchecker)

For using this add this in your app level build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.robohorse.gpversionchecker:gpversionchecker:1.0.8'
```

and in your launcher activity add this

```
new GPVersionChecker.Builder(this).create();
```

Comment: Ok, according to you I have to make a new apk which I am also assuming. Well, it's ok with your solution. Btw, I have find something in the below link which says "Note: If Google determines an app update will fix a critical security vulnerability, we may make certain app updates regardless of update settings in the app or on your device." Will it helpful? The link is: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en

Comment: Well that is only in the case of security issue and for that too you have to upload a new apk . Moreover if your app will be updated in future it can't be due to critical security risk everytime

Comment: Well, I have planned to upload a new apk with fixing this issue (version update notification). Ok thank you.